# Chrome console.error sourcemap support

Tags: google-chrome, coffeescript, source-maps

I'm using Chrome and have source maps enabled.  Coffeescript is compiling to JS with the sourcemap embedded at the bottom of the .js file.  I can see the *.coffee code in the source tab in the developer tools.

When there is an error in the console I would like to be able to click and jump to the coffeescript code.  Currently it only jumps to the .js code and there is no way to go to the .coffee code from there.

Is this supported?  If so, how can I make it work?

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue, but with concatenated JS files, did you find any information since you first asked the question?

Comment: No, I haven't but I haven't looked into it recently.  I'm just making do with reading the compiled JS.

Comment: The issue I'm experiencing seems like a chrome bug.  It only happens the first time I open the console, if I refresh the browser, or have the console open before navigating to the page, the console updates with links to the source-mapped files.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376409